# Non-Theoretical Applications of Partitions of Unity

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I am studying partitions of unity in Munkres' $\textit{Analysis on Manifolds}$ book. Are partitions of unity just theoretical tools, i.e. used to prove theorems, or do people actually apply them concretely to compute integrals in practice?

Comment: In my experience, you rarely have an explicit partition of unity. So, in my experience, that is mostly theoretical tool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Partitions of unity arise naturally in many applications related to affine spaces and [affine transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation#Alternative_definition). In fact, [barycentric coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system) are partitions of unity. So, there are lots of applications in geometry.

In other fields, also, there is often the idea of a "weighted average" where the weights necessarily sum to 1. This is common in finance/economics, for example.

The spline techniques mention by @William Krinsman are another example. Many curves in CAGD are so-called ["blended curves"](http://cagd.cs.byu.edu/~557/text/ch5.pdf) of the form
$$
\mathbf{P}(t) = \sum_{i=0}^n \phi_i(t) \mathbf{P}_i
$$
The blending functions must sum to 1, or else this definition is not well defined (it doesn't make sense to form an arbitrary sum of points).

The [Bernstein polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_polynomial) are one very common example of such blending functions -- they are used to construct [Bézier curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve) and [surfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_surface). But they have many other uses in approximation theory and probability, too.

[Lagrange polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) also form a partition of unity, and these have many uses.

So the short answer is that partitions of unity occur in many places in applied mathematics, computing, and engineering -- they are not just a theoretical concept.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert on numerical analysis, but based on the textbooks I have read on the subject, partitions of unity are used when defining basises of splines (see below). I think B-splines or Bezier splines; they are used in computer graphics.

http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/spline/bspline-property.html

http://arxiv.org/pdf/1410.5413.pdf

https://www.cs.unc.edu/~dm/UNC/COMP258/Papers/bsplbasic.pdf